# how to search from three different fields from one search input

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Those are my fields in my User table, i am using MySQL:

```
name                 
lastName              
surName
```

I have one search input where users can put any name or full name, but i don't know how to build a query for that, i'm pretty stuck.

I was working with the variations of the LIKE sentence but that didn't solve my problem:

```
SELECT u FROM User u
            WHERE u.name LIKE %rocky moon sun% OR u.lastName LIKE %rocky moon sun%  OR u.surName LIKE %rocky moon sun% '
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: I think you use 'AND' instead of 'OR'

Comment: In what way does the SELECT you wrote not solve your problem (other than the fact you're missing quotes around all of the `'%rocky moon sun%'` expressions)? @MuhammadFarrukhFaizy: No, `AND` would require that all three columns contain the value, which is not what the poster is attempting to do.

Comment: @KenWhite but when u need all three u must do use and for filtering otherwise OR give you if all true found regardless false column fields

Comment: @MuhammadFarrukhFaizy: The poster is trying to find a row where the name is in any one of the columns, not all of them. AND would require the name to be in all three columns on the same row. The poster wants OR.

Comment: okay if it wants any one to be true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can concat fields before you try to match them, Try this

```
SELECT 
       u 
FROM 
      User as u
WHERE 
      u.name LIKE %rocky moon sun% 
   OR u.lastName LIKE %rocky moon sun%  
   OR u.surName LIKE %rocky moon sun%
   OR concat (u.name,' ',u.lastName) like %rocky moon sun%
```

Comment: Thanks this was exactly what i was looking for! Now i can evaluate not only first name and last name but every possible search name case if i want to get picky :)

Answer (score 0):

Use table alias when u have to do joining between tables , I don't use table alias on simple queries

use this query instead 
For example if we want to search for an Id details

```
SELECT id FROM User WHERE name='Rocky moon sun' and lastName='Rocky moon son' and surname='Rock moon son';
```